# Can I change the target from a jQuery UI Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, tabs

I want to know if can I do this HTML markup works with jQuery UI Tabs for me? I know the basic markup, but I need to do like this code below.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="tab1">
        <p>Content from Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        <p>Content from Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        <p>Content from Tab 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your markup and code looks very similar to the demo code that's shown here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ (click the View Source link).  What exactly are you trying to do?